# How to convert pandas dataframe to nested dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am running Python 3.6 and Pandas 0.19.2 and have a DataFrame which looks as follows:

```
Name      Chain        Food       Healthy  

George    McDonalds    burger     False
George    KFC          chicken    False
John      Wendys       burger     False
John      McDonalds    salad      True
```

I want to transform this dataframe into a dict which looks as follows:

```
health_data = {'George': {'McDonalds': {'Food': 'burger', 'Healthy':False},
                          'KFC':       {'Food': 'chicken', 'Healthy':False}},
               'John':   {'Wendys':    {'Food': 'burger', 'Healthy':False},
                          'McDonalds': {'Food': 'salad', 'Healthy': True}}}
```

My thoughts so far are:

1. Use `df.groupby` to group the names column
2. Use `df.to_dict()` to transform the dataframe into a dictionary along the lines of:
       `health_data = input_data.set_index('Chain').T.to_dict()`

Thoughts? Thanks up front for the help.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I think you were very close.

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
df = df.groupby('Name')[['Chain','Food','Healthy']]
       .apply(lambda x: x.set_index('Chain').to_dict(orient='index'))
       .to_dict()

print (df)
{'George': {'KFC': {'Healthy': False, 'Food': 'chicken'}, 
           'McDonalds': {'Healthy': False, 'Food': 'burger'}}, 
'John': {'McDonalds': {'Healthy': True, 'Food': 'salad'},
         'Wendys': {'Healthy': False, 'Food': 'burger'}}}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked perfectly. One small question: what does the `[['Chain','Food','Healthy']]` part of the answer do?

Comment: It is filter columns, but if no other columns in `df`, it can be simplified like `df.groupby('Name').apply(lambda x: x.set_index('Chain').to_dict(orient='index')).to_dict()`

Comment: I was trying to do this for so long, didn't think to put the `.to_dict` inside the lambda, thanks as always Jozi :)

Comment: What if I want to set multiple index in `apply`? Do you have any idea?

Comment: what does set_index() do here and why do we need it?

Comment: @vhio - Because need kyes of nested dictionaries by column `Chain`

Comment: @jezrael How would you adjust this if there was another row that had "George, McDonalds, chicken, False"? In other words, there would be duplicate index values because "McDonalds" occurs twice for "George" so it would throw a ValueError since index must be unique for 'orient='index''.

Answer (score 12):

***Solution using dictionary comprehension and `groupby`:***

```
{n: grp.loc[n].to_dict('index')
 for n, grp in df.set_index(['Name', 'Chain']).groupby(level='Name')}

{'George': {'KFC': {'Food': 'chicken', 'Healthy': False},
  'McDonalds': {'Food': 'burger', 'Healthy': False}},
 'John': {'McDonalds': {'Food': 'salad', 'Healthy': True},
  'Wendys': {'Food': 'burger', 'Healthy': False}}}
```

***Solution using [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):***

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(dict)

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    d[row.Name][row.Chain] = row.drop(['Name', 'Chain']).to_dict()

dict(d)

{'George': {'KFC': {'Food': 'chicken', 'Healthy': False},
  'McDonalds': {'Food': 'burger', 'Healthy': False}},
 'John': {'McDonalds': {'Food': 'salad', 'Healthy': True},
  'Wendys': {'Food': 'burger', 'Healthy': False}}}
```

Comment: love the use of iterrows and default dict though it is slower than the group by for a little bit.  This would allow you to chain multiple loops together.  Another way would be to use a multi-index (but not appropriate for this example)