# nested dictionary of bin sizes from groupby multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, pandas-groupby

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3], 'b': [5,5,1,1,3,3,3,1,2,1,1,1,]})
>>> df
    a  b
0   1  5
1   1  5
2   1  1
3   1  1
4   2  3
5   2  3
6   2  3
7   2  1
8   3  2
9   3  1
10  3  1
11  3  1
>>> df.groupby(['a','b']).size().to_dict()
{(1, 5): 2, (3, 2): 1, (2, 3): 3, (3, 1): 3, (1, 1): 2, (2, 1): 1}
```

What I am getting is the counts of each `a` and `b` combination with a `tuple` of the pair as `key` but what I am trying to get to is:

```
{1: {5: 2, 1: 2}, 2: {3: 3, 1: 1}, 3: {2: 1, 1: 3} }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need an additional `groupby` inside a dict comprehension:

```
i = df.groupby(['a','b']).size().reset_index(level=1)
j = {k : dict(g.values) for k, g in i.groupby(level=0)}
```

```
print(j)
{
    1: {1: 2, 5: 2}, 
    2: {1: 1, 3: 3}, 
    3: {1: 3, 2: 1}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `collections.defaultdict` for an O(n) solution.

```
from collections import defaultdict

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3], 'b': [5,5,1,1,3,3,3,1,2,1,1,1,]})**Option 2: defaultdict**

d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))

for i, j in map(tuple, df.values):
    d[i][j] += 1

# defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>>,
#             {1: defaultdict(int, {1: 2, 5: 2}),
#              2: defaultdict(int, {1: 1, 3: 3}),
#              3: defaultdict(int, {1: 3, 2: 1})})
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. that is the approach I am currently using. I was just wandering whether pandas tools offer a vectorised approach to achieving this

Comment: My solution is *not* vectorised, it is a pure Python loop.

Comment: @Tony as a general rule, don't assume `groupby` or `apply` means `vectorized`... it doesn't.  jpp is right to highlight O(n) solutions.  However, cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ has provided an O(n) solution as well.  If performance is an issue, make sure to say so in your question.  It will inform us how to answer.  And jpp is right again to suggest you should test this on your data.  It is wrong to assume that a simple for loop is **always** worse.

Comment: @piRSquared I didn't mention it in my question because in my mind the simplest solution would involve something similar to this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41998624/how-to-convert-pandas-dataframe-to-nested-dictionary) that I could just not figure out myself. You are right in that I should be more explicit in my request. Thanks for your answers

Comment: I'll go on as why I like this approach.  Much of the overhead involved in looping (even when O(n)) is the creation of objects.  In my solution and cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's, we are creating Pandas objects within a comprehension.  jpp's solution avoids that overhead and simply adds to an existing key.  This should be efficient

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(Counter(zip(df.a, df.b)))
{
    n: d.xs(n).to_dict()
    for n, d in s.groupby(level=0)
}

{1: {1: 2, 5: 2}, 2: {1: 1, 3: 3}, 3: {1: 3, 2: 1}}
```