# Pandas: transforming dataframe to nested dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, data-structures, tree

I have this dataframe:

```
Month_Year  City_Name   Chain_Name Product_Name Product_Price
11-2021     London      Aldi       Pasta        2.33
11-2021     Bristol     Spar       Bananas      1.45
10-2021     London      Tesco      Olives       4.12
10-2021     Cardiff     Spar       Pasta        2.25
```

This dataframe will be displayed in **nested collapsible** which will expand in the following order:

```
Date_month:
    City_Name:
         Shop_name:
             Product_name : Price
```

Theefore, I want to transform the dataframe to the following structure:

```
{10-2021:
    {London:
        {Aldi:
            {Pasta:2.33}}},
    {Bristol:{
        {Spar:
            {Bananas:1.45}}}}
```

Essentially I want to `groupby` every element recursively, starting by purchase month. The closest thing I've found is the solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41998624/how-to-convert-pandas-dataframe-to-nested-dictionary), but as dictionary doesn't take duplicate values as I might have duplicate values in every column. Other than that, I am not sure if using a dictionary is the optimal answer for this problem.

My best guess is I have to use other DS type such as some type of tree, but couldn't find any way to do that.

Any advises?

Comment: Could you explain how you'd want to handle duplicate values in your final data structure? One workaround could be to tag a number to the duplicates. For example:  `{ ... "London":  { "Aldi 1", "Aldi 2"}  ...}`

Comment: I would like to keep the values unchanged; One way could be override built-in dict class to allow duplicate values, but not sure how efficient that solution would be. A tree like structure would be best probably; where each node represent one element of nested collapsible object in the front-end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group your dataframe by all columns except price, then create your dictionaries in a loop:

```
# if more than one price for one product in a chain, then calculate mean:
grouped_df = df.groupby(['Month_Year', 'City_Name', 'Chain_Name', 'Product_Name']).agg('mean')

result = dict()
nested_dict = dict()

for index, value in grouped_df.itertuples():
    for i, key in enumerate(index):
        if i == 0:
            if not key in result:
                result[key] = {}
            nested_dict = result[key]
        elif i == len(index) - 1:
            nested_dict[key] = value
        else:
            if not key in nested_dict:
                nested_dict[key] = {}
            nested_dict = nested_dict[key]

print(json.dumps(result, indent=4))
```

Changing your df to show nested dict and mean calculation to:

```
  Month_Year City_Name Chain_Name Product_Name  Product_Price
0    11-2021    London       Aldi        Pasta           2.33
1    11-2021    London       Aldi        Pasta           2.35
2    11-2021    London       Aldi       Olives           3.99
3    11-2021   Bristol       Spar      Bananas           1.45
4    10-2021    London      Tesco       Olives           4.12
5    10-2021   Cardiff       Spar        Pasta           2.25
```

You get the output:

```
{
    "10-2021": {
        "Cardiff": {
            "Spar": {
                "Pasta": 2.25
            }
        },
        "London": {
            "Tesco": {
                "Olives": 4.12
            }
        }
    },
    "11-2021": {
        "Bristol": {
            "Spar": {
                "Bananas": 1.45
            }
        },
        "London": {
            "Aldi": {
                "Olives": 3.99,
                "Pasta": 2.34
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @Tranbi this works perfectly but I'm trying to understand the code as a newbie. How is it that the `result` dictionary gets updated during each loop in the second for loop when `result` is only present in the `i==0` condition?

Comment: @MikeLee Since dictionaries are mutables `nested_dict = result[key]` assigns `nested_dict` to the reference of `result[key]`, ie. changing one will change both (think pointer in C++). I recommend you read about how python handles mutables/immutables.