# Data Frame to nested dictionary: Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I'm working with a dataframe:

```
   day        account_id     balance
  2022-11-01  ncw8y7     1.000000
  2022-11-02  ncw8y7     1.000424
```

Which I would like to transform into nested dictionary in which the 1st level is the account_id, 2nd level is category name "balances", 3rd level is the date which finally contains date as a list and balance:

```
{"account_id":"ncw8y7","balances":{"2022-11-01":{"day":[2022,11,01],"balance":1.00000},"2022-11-02":{"day":[2022,11,2],"balance":1.000424}}}
```

I tried to adopt solutions found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41998624/how-to-convert-pandas-dataframe-to-nested-dictionary) and that [post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/67578/export-pandas-dataframe-to-a-nested-dictionary-from-multiple-columns). However, fo some reason when using the first solution to try to learn how to do first part of this transformation (part that does not include yet a date as a list):

```
dict = results.groupby('account_id')[['day','balance']].apply(lambda x: x.set_index('day').to_dict(orient='index')).to_dict()
```

I am getting

```
{'ncw8y7': {datetime.date(2022, 11, 1): {'balance': 1.00000},
  datetime.date(2022, 11, 2): {'balance': 1.000424}}}
```

I don't get why `'day'` variable is getting formated in this way: `datetime.date(2022, 11, 1)`. Is that because of getting it as index? How would you suggest me to adopt the `dict` function to get to the desired effect?

Comment: Please provide a proper way to recreate your initial Dataframe like `df.to_dict()`

Comment: data = {'day':  ['2022-11-01', '2022-11-02'],
        'account_id': ['ncw8y7', 'ncw8y7'],
         'balance': [1.000000, 1.000424]
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

Comment: Please edit your question. Also with multiple account ids, you would end up with a list of dictionaries. Is it what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
dfx=df.groupby('account_id').agg(list)
final=[]
for i in dfx.index:
    final.append({"account_id":i,"balances":{dfx['day'][i][j]:{"day":[dfx['day'][i][j]],"balance":dfx['balance'][i][j]} for j in range(len(dfx['day'][i]))}})
```

**Output**:

```
[
{
    "account_id":"ncw8y7",
    "balances":{
        "2022-11-01":{
            "day":[
                "2022-11-01"
            ],
            "balance":1.0
        },
        "2022-11-02":{
            "day":[
                "2022-11-02"
            ],
            "balance":1.000424
        }
    }
}

]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try using the to_json() method as its output is in dict format

```
data.to_json('path',orient='records')
```

it will provide the format u need but if you want to work on the data after the conversion better option is to_dict() I guess ([source](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html))

```
df.to_dict(orient=records)

orient: {‘dict’, ‘list’, ‘series’, ‘split’, ‘tight’, ‘records’, ‘index’}

Determines the type of the values of the dictionary.

‘dict’ (default) : dict like {column -> {index -> value}}

‘list’ : dict like {column -> [values]}

‘series’ : dict like {column -> Series(values)}

‘split’ : dict like {‘index’ -> [index], ‘columns’ -> [columns], ‘data’ -> [values]}

‘tight’ : dict like {‘index’ -> [index], ‘columns’ -> [columns], ‘data’ -> [values], ‘index_names’ -> [index.names], ‘column_names’ -> [column.names]}

‘records’ : list like [{column -> value}, … , {column -> value}]

‘index’ : dict like {index -> {column -> value}}
```