# How to convert pandas DataFrame to nested dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a pandas DataFrame like this:

| id | unit | step | phase | start_or_end_of_phase | op_name | occurence |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 50l | LOAD | start | P12load5 | 2 |
| 2 | A | 50l | LOAD | end | P12load5 | 2 |
| 3 | A | 50l | STIR | start | P12s5 | 4 |
| 4 | A | 50l | STIR | end | P13s5 | 3 |
| 5 | A | 50l | COLLECT | start | F7_col1 | 1 |
| 6 | A | 50l | COLLECT | end | H325_col1 | 1 |
| 7 | A | 1000l | SET_TEMP | start | xyz | 2 |
| 8 | A | 1000l | SET_TEMP | end | qwe | 3 |
| 9 | A | 1000l | SET_TEMP2 | start | asf | 4 |
| 10 | A | 1000l | SET_TEMP2 | end | fdsa | 5 |
| 11 | A | 1000l | FILTER | start | 4fags | 1 |
| 11 | A | 1000l | FILTER | end | mllsgrs_1 | 1 |
| 12 | B | MACHINE1 | ... | ... | ... | ... |

...and want to create nested dictionaries like this:

```
A = {50l : {
       'LOAD' :
                {'start':{'op_name' : 'p12load5',
                           'occurrence': 2},
                 'end':{'op_name': 'P12load5',
                        'occurrence': 2}},
        'STIR': 
                {'start':{'op_name' : 'P12s5',
                           'occurrence': 4},
                 'end':{'op_name': 'P13s5',
                        'occurrence': 3}},
        'COLLECT': 
                {'start':{'op_name' : 'F7_col1',
                           'occurrence': 1},
                 'end':{'op_name': 'H325_col1',
                        'occurrence': 1}}
          }, 
    1000l : {
       'SET_TEMP' : ....
```

I have been trying to combine groupby() with to_dict() but couldn't wrap my head around it.
My last attempt was this (based on [How to convert pandas dataframe to nested dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41998624/how-to-convert-pandas-dataframe-to-nested-dictionary)):

```
populated_dict = process_steps_table.groupby(['unit', 'step', 'phase', 'start_or_end_phase']).apply(lambda x: x.set_index('start_or_end_phase').to_dict(orient='index')).to_dict()
```

and got his error: DataFrame index must be unique for orient='index'.

I am not sure if I have to apply the set_index() lambda function to the groups and why.

Comment: The linked question is 2-level index/key combination. You need to add another `groupby` if you want another layer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to reshape your dataframe before export as dictionary:

```
nested_cols = ['step', 'phase', 'start_or_end_of_phase']
value_cols = ['op_name', 'occurence']

# Reshape your dataframe
df1 = df.set_index(nested_cols)[value_cols].stack()

# Export nested dict
d = {}

# items():
# t -> flatten index to convert to nested dict
# v -> last level of your nested dict (values)
for t, v in df1.items():
    e = d.setdefault(t[0], {})  # create a new entry with an empty dict
    for k in t[1:-1]:
        e = e.setdefault(k, {})  # create a nested sub entry with an empty dict
    e[t[-1]] = v  # finally add values when you reach the end of the index
```

Output

```
import json  # just for a best representation
print(json.dumps(d, indent=4))

# Output
{
    "50l": {
        "LOAD": {
            "start": {
                "op_name": "P12load5",
                "occurence": 2
            },
            "end": {
                "op_name": "P12load5",
                "occurence": 2
            }
        },
        "STIR": {
            "start": {
                "op_name": "P12s5",
                "occurence": 4
            },
            "end": {
                "op_name": "P13s5",
                "occurence": 3
            }
        },
        "COLLECT": {
            "start": {
                "op_name": "F7_col1",
                "occurence": 1
            },
            "end": {
                "op_name": "H325_col1",
                "occurence": 1
            }
        }
    },
    "1000l": {
        "SET_TEMP": {
            "start": {
                "op_name": "xyz",
                "occurence": 2
            },
            "end": {
                "op_name": "qwe",
                "occurence": 3
            }
        },
        "SET_TEMP2": {
            "start": {
                "op_name": "asf",
                "occurence": 4
            },
            "end": {
                "op_name": "fdsa",
                "occurence": 5
            }
        },
        "FILTER": {
            "start": {
                "op_name": "4fags",
                "occurence": 1
            },
            "end": {
                "op_name": "mllsgrs_1",
                "occurence": 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is awesome, I get the output I needed! But it would be great if you could add some explanation because I have to adapt your code to my actual data which is even more complex than the table in the example.

Comment: I added some explanation to my code. Put nested levels into index and keep values as columns. The first loop is to bootstrap the dict (first level of index) while the second loop create nested levels. At the end, put columns values to the dict.