# Dataframe to multilevel nested dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with the columns= ['country_code','customer_state','customer_city','returns_count']
Here is a sample-

```
[{'country_code': 'IN',
  'customer_state': 'Uttar Pradesh',
  'customer_city': 'Agra',
  'returns_count': 100},
 {'country_code': 'IN',
  'customer_state': 'Uttar Pradesh',
  'customer_city': 'Meerut',
  'returns_count': 120},
 {'country_code': 'IN',
  'customer_state': 'Uttar Pradesh',
  'customer_city': 'Lucknow',
  'returns_count': 110},
 {'country_code': 'IN',
  'customer_state': 'Uttar Pradesh',
  'customer_city': 'Noida',
  'returns_count': 90},
 {'country_code': 'IN',
  'customer_state': 'Karnataka',
  'customer_city': 'Bangalore',
  'returns_count': 100},
 {'country_code': 'IN',
  'customer_state': 'Karnataka',
  'customer_city': 'Mysore',
  'returns_count': 200},
 {'country_code': 'US',
  'customer_state': 'California',
  'customer_city': 'LA',
  'returns_count': 180},
 {'country_code': 'US',
  'customer_state': 'California',
  'customer_city': 'San Jose',
  'returns_count': 150},
 {'country_code': 'US',
  'customer_state': 'California',
  'customer_city': 'San Francisco',
  'returns_count': 200},
 {'country_code': 'US',
  'customer_state': 'California',
  'customer_city': 'San Diego',
  'returns_count': 140}]
```

I want to convert it into a nested dictionary on the levels- first level is 'country_code', inside which we have the 'customer_state', and for each 'customer_state' we have the 'customer_city' and their respective 'returns_count'

Expected output-

```
{'IN':
  {'Uttar Pradesh' : {'Agra' : {'returns_count':100},
                      'Meerut' : {'returns_count':120},
                      'Lucknow' : {'returns_count':110},
                      'Noida' : {'returns_count' :90}},
   'Karnataka' : {'Bengaluru' :{'returns_count':100},
                  'Mysore' : {'returns_count' :200}},
    .....
 
       },
 'US':{.................}
```

I am using the following code, but it is giving error-

```
df = df.groupby('country_code')[['customer_state', 'customer_city', 'returns_value',
       'returns_count', 'orders_count', 'return_rate', 'latitude',
       'longitude']].apply(lambda x:x.set_index('customer_state').to_dict(orient='index')).to_dict()
```

Answer (score 1):

[A generic way to create nested dict](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75148486/15239951):

```
nested_cols = ['country_code', 'customer_state', 'customer_city']
value_cols = ['returns_count']

# Reshape your dataframe
df1 = df.set_index(nested_cols)[value_cols].stack()

# Export nested dict
d = {}

# items():
# t -> flatten index to convert to nested dict
# v -> last level of your nested dict (values)
for t, v in df1.items():
    e = d.setdefault(t[0], {})  # create a new entry with an empty dict
    for k in t[1:-1]:
        e = e.setdefault(k, {})  # create a nested sub entry with an empty dict
    e[t[-1]] = v  # finally add values when you reach the end of the index
```

Output:

```
>>> d
{'IN': {'Uttar Pradesh': {'Agra': {'returns_count': 100},
   'Meerut': {'returns_count': 120},
   'Lucknow': {'returns_count': 110},
   'Noida': {'returns_count': 90}},
  'Karnataka': {'Bangalore': {'returns_count': 100},
   'Mysore': {'returns_count': 200}}},
 'US': {'California': {'LA': {'returns_count': 180},
   'San Jose': {'returns_count': 150},
   'San Francisco': {'returns_count': 200},
   'San Diego': {'returns_count': 140}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use nested dictionary comprehension for expected ouput:

```
out = {k: {k1: v1.set_index('customer_city').to_dict(orient='index')
           for k1, v1 in v.groupby('customer_state')}
       for k, v in df.set_index(['country_code','customer_state']).groupby('country_code')}
```

---

```
print (out)

{
    'IN': {
        'Karnataka': {
            'Bangalore': {
                'returns_count': 100
            },
            'Mysore': {
                'returns_count': 200
            }
        },
        'Uttar Pradesh': {
            'Agra': {
                'returns_count': 100
            },
            'Meerut': {
                'returns_count': 120
            },
            'Lucknow': {
                'returns_count': 110
            },
            'Noida': {
                'returns_count': 90
            }
        }
    },
    'US': {
        'California': {
            'LA': {
                'returns_count': 180
            },
            'San Jose': {
                'returns_count': 150
            },
            'San Francisco': {
                'returns_count': 200
            },
            'San Diego': {
                'returns_count': 140
            }
        }
    }
}
```