# Convert a dataframe to a nested dictionary with multiple levels

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a cleaner way to convert my dataframe to a nested dictionary with more than one level? If possible, I want to avoid the double `for` loop that I needed to achieve the result.

```
from pprint import pprint

a = pd.DataFrame([
    {'col1': 'A', 'col2': 'Person 1', 'height': 1, 'weight': 10},
    {'col1': 'A', 'col2': 'Person 1', 'height': 2, 'weight': 20},
    {'col1': 'A', 'col2': 'Person 1', 'height': 3, 'weight': 30},
    {'col1': 'A', 'col2': 'Person 2', 'height': 4, 'weight': 40},
    {'col1': 'A', 'col2': 'Person 2', 'height': 5, 'weight': 50},
    {'col1': 'A', 'col2': 'Person 2', 'height': 6, 'weight': 60},
    {'col1': 'B', 'col2': 'Person 1', 'height': 11, 'weight': 101},
    {'col1': 'B', 'col2': 'Person 1', 'height': 21, 'weight': 201},
    {'col1': 'B', 'col2': 'Person 1', 'height': 31, 'weight': 301},
    {'col1': 'B', 'col2': 'Person 2', 'height': 41, 'weight': 401},
    {'col1': 'B', 'col2': 'Person 2', 'height': 51, 'weight': 501},
    {'col1': 'B', 'col2': 'Person 2', 'height': 61, 'weight': 601},
])

result = {}
for col1, j in a.groupby('col1'):
    result[col1] = {}
    for col2, n in j.groupby('col2'):
        result[col1][col2] = n.to_dict(orient='records')

pprint(result)
```

Result:

```
{'A': {'Person 1': [{'col1': 'A',
                     'col2': 'Person 1',
                     'height': 1,
                     'weight': 10},
                    {'col1': 'A',
                     'col2': 'Person 1',
                     'height': 2,
                     'weight': 20},
                    {'col1': 'A',
                     'col2': 'Person 1',
                     'height': 3,
                     'weight': 30}],
       'Person 2': [{'col1': 'A',
                     'col2': 'Person 2',
                     'height': 4,
                     'weight': 40},
                    {'col1': 'A',
                     'col2': 'Person 2',
                     'height': 5,
                     'weight': 50},
                    {'col1': 'A',
                     'col2': 'Person 2',
                     'height': 6,
                     'weight': 60}]},
 'B': {'Person 1': [{'col1': 'B',
                     'col2': 'Person 1',
                     'height': 11,
                     'weight': 101},
                    {'col1': 'B',
                     'col2': 'Person 1',
                     'height': 21,
                     'weight': 201},
                    {'col1': 'B',
                     'col2': 'Person 1',
                     'height': 31,
                     'weight': 301}],
       'Person 2': [{'col1': 'B',
                     'col2': 'Person 2',
                     'height': 41,
                     'weight': 401},
                    {'col1': 'B',
                     'col2': 'Person 2',
                     'height': 51,
                     'weight': 501},
                    {'col1': 'B',
                     'col2': 'Person 2',
                     'height': 61,
                     'weight': 601}]}}
```

I tried to use something like this, but couldn't figure out how to nest `col2` properly.

```
a.groupby('col1').apply(lambda x: x.set_index(
    'col2').to_dict(orient='records')).to_dict()
```

Comment: [You can visit here, the solution is ok ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41998624/how-to-convert-pandas-dataframe-to-nested-dictionary)

Comment: @MarcSteven I saw that answer, but that didn't work for what I was trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the result you want with a nested groupby on `col1`, then `col2`:

```py
out = a.groupby('col1').apply(
    lambda x: x.groupby('col2').apply(
        lambda y:y.to_dict('records')
    )
).to_dict('index')
```

Output:

```
{
  'A': {
    'Person 1': [
      {'col1': 'A', 'col2': 'Person 1', 'height': 1, 'weight': 10},
      {'col1': 'A', 'col2': 'Person 1', 'height': 2, 'weight': 20},
      {'col1': 'A', 'col2': 'Person 1', 'height': 3, 'weight': 30}
    ],
    'Person 2': [
      {'col1': 'A', 'col2': 'Person 2', 'height': 4, 'weight': 40},
      {'col1': 'A', 'col2': 'Person 2', 'height': 5, 'weight': 50},
      {'col1': 'A', 'col2': 'Person 2', 'height': 6, 'weight': 60}
    ]
  },
  'B': {
    'Person 1': [
      {'col1': 'B', 'col2': 'Person 1', 'height': 11, 'weight': 101},
      {'col1': 'B', 'col2': 'Person 1', 'height': 21, 'weight': 201},
      {'col1': 'B', 'col2': 'Person 1', 'height': 31, 'weight': 301}
    ],
    'Person 2': [
      {'col1': 'B', 'col2': 'Person 2', 'height': 41, 'weight': 401},
      {'col1': 'B', 'col2': 'Person 2', 'height': 51, 'weight': 501},
      {'col1': 'B', 'col2': 'Person 2', 'height': 61, 'weight': 601}
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this if you are okay with list comprehension:

```py
result = {col1: {col2: n.to_dict(orient='records') for col2, n in j.groupby('col2')} for col1, j in a.groupby('col1')}
```

Comment: I should've specified that I was looking for a "pandas" solution. I can convert what I had to use list comprehension, but that wasn't what I was after.